# What is the difference between calling LayoutInflater directly and not?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I went through some tutorials, and in the Android Doc, it says not to access LayoutInflater directly when instantiating it. Example from the google Doc:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

The tutorial I went through is this one:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
```

So what I don't really understand is what the difference is besides the obvious different code. Any explanation much appreciated. I assume that the Android Doc should be the one we follow, but I am not sure if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you open up the Android source you can see that the LayoutInflator.from method looks like so:

```
/**
 * Obtains the LayoutInflater from the given context.
 */
public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (LayoutInflater == null) {
        throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
    }
    return LayoutInflater;
}
```

That means the two lines of code in your question do the same thing. Not sure what the tutorial you read says exactly but I don't see any difference in functionality. Using the `from` method is nice since it requires a little less typing, that's it.

Comment: Haha! Wow, thanks! That really helped. I would have had another question but you even answered that one. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

You are getting `LayoutInflater Service Provider` from `System Manager`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
```

You are using `static` method from `LayoutInflater Class`

I would say that difference is only in code and how you write this also calling stack but result is same - you will get `LayoutInflater`.

More about [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Regards