# ExpandableListView won't populate

Tags: android, fragment, expandablelistview

I'm trying to inflate an ExpandableListView in a Fragment and use a setAdapter.  I succeed properly when I don't use it in a fragment, but in Fragment, I either get errors (NullPointerException) or the ExpandableListView won't be populated.

```
package com.stylingandroid.basicactionbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class Friends extends Fragment
{
    private static List<Country> Countries;
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    private CountryAdapter adapter;
    private View V;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {

        V = inflater.inflate( R.layout.frag2, container, false );
        LoadCountries();
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) V.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter = new CountryAdapter(this, Countries);

        return V;
    }


    private void LoadCountries() {
        Countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

        ArrayList<String> citiesAustralia = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList("Brisbane", "Hobart", "Melbourne", "Sydney"));
        Countries.add(new Country("Australia", citiesAustralia));

        ArrayList<String> citiesChina = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList("Beijing", "Chuzhou", "Dongguan", "Shangzhou"));
        Countries.add(new Country("China", citiesChina));
    }
    }
```

frag2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

package com.stylingandroid.basicactionbar;



import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
    {
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mFragName;

        public MyTabListener( Activity activity, String fragName )
        {
            mActivity = activity;
            mFragName = fragName;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
        {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate( mActivity, mFragName );
            ft.add( android.R.id.content, mFragment );
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
        {
            ft.remove( mFragment );
            mFragment = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );       
        Intent intent;

        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS );

        Tab tab = ab.newTab()
                .setText( R.string.title_param )
                .setTabListener( 
                        new MyTabListener( this, 
                                Param.class.getName() ) );
        ab.addTab( tab );

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Friends.class);
        tab = ab.newTab()
                .setText( R.string.title_friends )


                .setTabListener( 
                        new MyTabListener( this, 
                                Friends.class.getName() ) );
        ab.addTab( tab );

        tab = ab.newTab()
                .setText( R.string.title_maps )
                .setTabListener( 
                        new MyTabListener( this, 
                                Maps.class.getName() ) );
        ab.addTab( tab );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item )
    {
        boolean ret;
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_settings)
        {
            // Handle Settings
            ret = true;
        } else
        {
            ret = super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

CountryAdapter:

```
package com.stylingandroid.basicactionbar;

import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class CountryAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private List<Country> countries;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CountryAdapter(Context context) {
        this.countries = countries;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public CountryAdapter(Friends friends, List<Country> countries2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return countries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return countries.get(groupPosition).getCities().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return countries.get(groupPosition).getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return countries.get(groupPosition).getCities().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView) convertView).setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView)convertView).setText(getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i2) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The part, I guess, that is wrong is there:

```
public CountryAdapter(Context context) {
    this.countries = countries;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to use the (Context, context) for the fragment Friends.  Any idea?

Thank you in advance! :)

EDIT:

I used the code of Gaurav Vashisth and I can a NullPointerException. Here is the stack trace.

```
10-12 19:11:52.105: D/dalvikvm(2203): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 41K, 6% free 2553K/2716K, paused 62ms, total 66ms
10-12 19:11:52.116: I/dalvikvm-heap(2203): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.215MB for 635812-byte allocation
10-12 19:11:52.265: D/dalvikvm(2203): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 3172K/3340K, paused 141ms, total 141ms
10-12 19:11:52.525: D/dalvikvm(2203): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3178K/3340K, paused 8ms+176ms, total 264ms
10-12 19:11:53.405: D/libEGL(2203): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
10-12 19:11:53.495: D/(2203): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a155620, tid 2203
10-12 19:11:53.616: D/libEGL(2203): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
10-12 19:11:53.625: D/libEGL(2203): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
10-12 19:11:53.725: W/EGL_emulation(2203): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-12 19:11:53.766: D/OpenGLRenderer(2203): Enabling debug mode 0
10-12 19:12:11.858: D/AndroidRuntime(2203): Shutting down VM
10-12 19:12:11.858: W/dalvikvm(2203): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.stylingandroid.basicactionbar.CountryAdapter.getGroupCount(CountryAdapter.java:26)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getCount(ExpandableListConnector.java:397)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:470)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.stylingandroid.basicactionbar.Friends.onCreateView(Friends.java:32)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-12 19:12:11.906: E/AndroidRuntime(2203):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 19:17:12.528: I/Process(2203): Sending signal. PID: 2203 SIG: 9
```

EDIT 2: With the following code, I get the NullPointerException, stack trace above modified.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState )
{

    LoadCountries();
    V = inflater.inflate( R.layout.frag2, container, false );
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) V.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

    adapter = new CountryAdapter(getActivity(), Countries);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return V;
}
```

CountryAdapter:

```
private List<Country> countries;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CountryAdapter(Context context, List<Country> contries) {
    this.countries = countries;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

Comment: pls post the stack trace

Comment: what is line 27 `CountryAdapter.java` and do you get the exception after making the corrections suggested

Comment: From the logs I guess countries arraylist was null at that moment.

Comment: probably that is because countries might not be populated before passing the same to adapter. So moving adapter initialization to the end of `LoadCountries()` is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that in your onCreateView method you are using the adapter method before initializing it. Use it this way

```
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState )
{

    V = inflater.inflate( R.layout.frag2, container, false );
    LoadCountries();
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) V.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

    adapter = new CountryAdapter(getActivity(), Countries);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return V;
}
```

To get reference of activity in a fragment use getActivity()

Besides it

So that your Adapter's constructor becomes

```
public CountryAdapter(Context context, List<Country> countries) {
    this.countries = countries;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

I would also like to point out that according to java conventions method names start with lower case letters. So It would we great if you rename `LoadCountries()` to `loadCountries()`

Comment: Initialize it before using it in expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: yes i agree on that part but you don't need this LayoutInflater `inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)` and `this` does not refer to activity context

Comment: Use it inside the Adapter's constructor.

Comment: even this `inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)` is fine

Comment: I wonder what's the difference between these two APIs to get the LayoutInflater. It would be great if you throw some light on the difference between the two.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776676/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-layoutinflater-directly-and-not

Comment: Changing inflater = `LayoutInflater.from(context)`; to `inflater = LayoutInflater.get(context)`; gives this error:
The method get(Context) is undefined for the type LayoutInflater

Comment: leave it as inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

Comment: Please check if you are sending null List to the adapter in the constructor.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+expandableListView.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
This displays 0.

Comment: @NicolasLamoureux did you try the suggestion in my post

Comment: @Raghunandan Solved! The problem was `public CountryAdapter(Context context, List<Country> contries) {`  instrad of `countries`...

thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

Use `getActivity()`

```
public final Activity getActivity ()

Added in API level 11
Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.
```

Replace

```
  adapter = new CountryAdapter(this, Countries);
```

By

```
  adapter = new CountryAdapter(getActivity(), Countries);
```

Also you need to reverse

```
 expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
 adapter = new CountryAdapter(this, Countries);
```

to

```
 adapter = new CountryAdapter(getActivity(), Countries);
 expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Edit:

Also it would be better to change to

```
  private void LoadCountries() {
    Countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

    ArrayList<String> citiesAustralia = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList("Brisbane", "Hobart", "Melbourne", "Sydney"));
    Countries.add(new Country("Australia", citiesAustralia));

    ArrayList<String> citiesChina = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList("Beijing", "Chuzhou", "Dongguan", "Shangzhou"));
    Countries.add(new Country("China", citiesChina));
    adapter = new CountryAdapter(getActivity(), Countries);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

   }
```